# Add D: Drive to Windows Server 2016 Docker Images

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016

How do I add a D: drive to the microsoft/windowsservercore base image?
My Windows Server 2016 server has a D: drive.  The server is an AWS instance.
This is with native Docker installed and not the "Docker for Windows" that has been around for a while.

Answer (score 7):

We got it to work.  Essentially, we're adding a symbolic link in the registry.

Add this to the dockerfile:

```
RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command \
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path C:\drived ; \
    New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices' -Name 'D:'  -Value '\??\C:\drived' -PropertyType String;
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this using the subst command:

```
mkdir c:\drived
subst d: c:\drived
```

I think such a drive is only visible in the current session, so it wouldn't work if you are using Windows services.