# Create D drive in a docker container

Tags: windows, docker

Is it possible to create a new partition with a drive letter other than C: in a docker Windows container?

I need a D:\ and an E:\ drive for some software.

Comment: its not a good idea to put the software on another drive for now... but Their is a way to move your docker-desktop-data to your other drive.. check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AyEw7JsHt9I

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do it from an existing image, but if you make a Dockerfile like so:

```
FROM <Base image like microsoft/dotnet-framework>
VOLUME ["D:"]
# Rest of Docker file here
```

The Windows container will create a D: Drive.

Answer (score 0):

This works in native Windows Server containers, but I had issues with it on docker-for-windows (Windows 10)

`VOLUME ["D:"]`

So for those in the same predicament, I found this worked for both.

[Add D: Drive to Windows Server 2016 Docker Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40225407/add-d-drive-to-windows-server-2016-docker-images)