# Creating Partition Drive E in a target windows Server using Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine, powershell-remoting, docker-for-windows

Is it possible to create a new partition with a drive E: in a docker Windows container?

I tried  option symbolic link in the registry and volume E in a dockerfile,it generates a drive in a container.But when i run this container in my localhost it doesnot create any E partition drive.

I also tried new partition powershell command to create new drive in the target windows host using dockerfile, but it shows like "msft doesnot have disknumber drive" in building the image itelf.

So what i need is, i dont have any drive other than c in my target windows host,so using dockerfile i need to create a drive by downloading my drive creation image as a base image.

Can anyone suggest me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, you cannot use tooling isolated inside a Docker container to control low-level host hardware details like this.

Comment: So how can we create disk partition drive inside a container, so that we can able to create drive in target windows host while running this created base image

Comment: You don't.  Run the tool directly on the host, with administrator permissions.  A principal design goal of Docker is that containers can't generally reconfigure the host like this.

Answer (score 0):

But i think Volume command in docker will create a disk drive in target windows like the below link [Create D drive in a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788775/create-d-drive-in-a-docker-container).

Correct me if any wrong.

Comment: By using VOLUME  command , it will create a drive in container  but am not sure whether this container connecting to windows target host ,it will create a drive.