# I am new at docker i am creating a docker file for installing visual studio tools but i dont want to use my C drive . Having a issue with COPY command

Tags: visual-studio, docker, powershell, copy

[Copy error while running docker build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCrcX.png)

My docker file is

## escape=`

ARG WIN_VER="ltsc2019"

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:$WIN_VER

## visual c++

WORKDIR D:\DockerProject\ 
CMD D: 
COPY Install.cmd D:\DockerProject\temp\ 
ADD https://aka.ms/vscollect.exe D:\DockerProject\collect.exe

## Download channel for fixed install.

ARG CHANNEL_URL=https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/channel 
ADD ${CHANNEL_URL} D:\DockerProject\TEMP\VisualStudio.chman

## Download and install Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017 for native desktop workload.

ADD https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_buildtools.exe D:\DockerProject\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe 
RUN D:\DockerProject\TEMP\Install.cmd D:\DockerProject\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache `--channelUri D:\DockerProject\TEMP\VisualStudio.chman`
--installChannelUri D:\DockerProject\TEMP\VisualStudio.chman  `--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools --includeRecommended`
--installPath D:\DockerProject\Installs

## Use developer command prompt and start PowerShell if no other command specified.

ENTRYPOINT D:\DockerProject\Installs\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat && 
CMD ["powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]

Comment: what does this have to do with powershell? i don't see any PoSh stuff in what you show ...

Comment: I have added a image also i am kept getting a error if runs the same command on powershell it runs fine but giving issue "invalid COPY: Windows does not support destinations not on the system drive (C:)"  with docker @Lee_Dailey

Comment: thank you for the added info. [*grin*] ///// windows DOES support drives other than `c:`, so that error is  _probably_ from your docker stuff, not from PoSh or from windows itself.

Comment: i think you skiped a step, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40225407/add-d-drive-to-windows-server-2016-docker-images