# Docker windows how to mount folder on other drive E:\ or D:\

Tags: windows, docker, volume, mount

How to mount a folder inside a container on another drive letter? I've tried building the image with the volume of that drive but the same error is thrown. I've also tried to create the volumes [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40225407/add-d-drive-to-windows-server-2016-docker-images) way with no luck.

```
PS C:\vs-2017> docker run --rm -it -v E:\xml-data:E:\xml-data  mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8
docker: Error response from daemon: hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem 8653b905fd8f08fde5c0dfe0795635cf2d2a265e38686dea50ce0ae00bf7f295: The parameter
is incorrect.
```

Comment: Real actual drive, or just a network share?

Comment: It's an actual drive. The thing is it works when mounting in C: like this -v E:\xml-data:C:\xml-data , but not like this -v E:\xml-data:E:\xml-data