# How to add D Drive to the windows container

Tags: docker, docker-volume, windows-container

I am trying to containerize a legacy frozen application. It requires D drive to be present else installation fails. I tried following the instructions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40225407/add-d-drive-to-windows-server-2016-docker-images).

Docker build successful but my package installation fails. When I go into interactive mode, I cannot do

> cd D:\

My docker file -

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
RUN dism.exe /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:iis-webserver /NoRestart
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command \
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path C:\drived ; \
    New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices' -Name 'D:'  -Value '\??\C:\drived' -PropertyType String;
RUN mkdir "D:\test"
SHELL ["cmd", "/C"]
CMD [ "cmd" ]
```

Comment: Rather than using dism to install IIS, can I recommend you use the IIS image? It comes with IIS pre-installed and Service Monitor which allows you to not exit the image if you don't have an EntryPoint. Image is: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis:windowsservercore-ltsc2019

Answer (score 1):

You don't go into any detail about "I cannot do `cd D:\`", so I'm guessing.

In Windows `cmd.exe`, there is a separate working directory for each drive. This means that `cd D:\` changes the working directory for the `D:` drive, but *doesn't* change the working directory that you're looking at (because you're still on the `C:` drive).

You need to `cd /d D:\` to change the current drive along with the working directory.